# Data is not getting posted with jquery $.post() method

Tags: jquery

Am not getting data code posted and when I opened html document in network tab its not showing POST to php document

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(document).delegate('#target','submit',function(e) {
       var data=$("#target:input").serializeArray();
       alert ('hi'); 
       $.post("signin.php",data,function(json) {
           if(json.status=='fail') {
               alert(json.message);
               return false;
           }
           else if(json.status=='success') {
               alert(json.message);
               return false;
           }
      }).error({alert("internal error");});
   });
 });
```

php code into which i want to post my data is:

```
<?php
 echo $_POST['txt1'].$_POST['txt2'];
 ?>
```

and html form through which i want to post data is

```
<div class="sld_dwn">
  <form class="sign_in_form" id='target'>
  <div>
  <a class="sign_in_data" >email:</a>
  </br>
  <input type="text" class="sign_in_box" name='txt1'>
  <a class="sign_in_data1">password:</a>
  </br>
  <input type="password" class="sign_in_box1"name='txt2' >
  </div>
  <a href='http://localhost' class="forgot">forgot password</a></br>
  <!--<input type="checkbox"><a class="stay">stay signin</a>-->
  <input type='submit' class="but_signin1" value='Sign in'>
  </form>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change code part:

```
}).error({alert("internal error");});
```

to

```
}).error( function() { alert("internal error"); });
```

And

```
var data=$("#target:input").serializeArray();
```

to

```
var data=$("#target").serialize();
```

or

```
var data=$("#target").find("input").serialize();
```

Add dataType to your POST, like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(document).delegate('#target','submit',function(e) {
       var data=$("#target:input").serializeArray();
       alert ('hi'); 
       $.post("signin.php",data,function(json) {
           if(json.status=='fail') {
               alert(json.message);
               return false;
           }
           else if(json.status=='success') {
               alert(json.message);
               return false;
           }
      }, "json").error({alert("internal error");});
   });
 });
```

And php

```
<?php
  echo json_encode( array("status" => "success") );
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for Sudhir it has worked better but json.status is neither taking false or success can you please help me with that my modified code is

Comment: `$(document).ready(function()
    {
    $(document).delegate('#target','submit',function(e)
    {
    var data=$("#target").find("input").serializeArray();
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post("signin.php",data,function(json)
    {
    if(json.status=='fail')
    {
    alert(json.message);
    return false;
    }
    else 
    if(json.status=='success')
    {
    alert(json.message);
    return false;
    }
    }).error(function (){alert("internal error"); });
    });
    })`;

Comment: does your response from php contain status field... like from php echo json_encode(array("status" => "some_status")); In this case you get the json.status value....

Comment: `<?php
   echo json_encode(array("status" => "success"));
    ?>`

Comment: add "json" as dataType for your $.post as shows above in edited answer